# Mutliprocessing in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing to speed up my program.

```
import multiprocessing

def read(li,i):
    name = "char"
    #updating my list here
    li[i:i] = [name]
    print(li)#this gives [4, 'char', 1]

def write(i):
    pass

li= []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 1
    li =[4]
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = read,args = (li,i,)) 
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = write,args = (i,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()  
    p2.join()
    print(li)#this gives [4, 1] instead of the expected [4, 'char', 1]
```

This is just the basic program. In the original program, I need to update a list like this. The list variable `li` is not getting updated globally. I tried doing the same without multiprocessing, which works fine by the way. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Processes do not share memory. Variables are at most *per process* global. Each process works on a copy of the original ``li``, or a newly created process-local ``li``.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the shared state facilities also provided by the `multiprocessing` module.

Given you mention updating a list, `Array()` will probably be useful:

```
li = Array("i", [4])
```

If you need to update the variable `i` too, you'll need to do something similar.

See the documentation for details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes